# Cannot disable Sound Alert

Tags: sound, effects

i'm using Asus EeePC 1015PX, installed Ubuntu 14.04.3, i cannot disable the sound Alert mute sound volume of the sound alert in the sound effects..
Please help me to disable the sound alert while i still can turn on the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Open **System Settings** and go in :  **Sound** > **Sound Effects** tab.

Here you will see a checkbox to mute Alert volume :

[image: mute alert]